# Cubevalue returning blank (zero length string) when a member is a Cubset function

Tags: excel, powerpivot

#### The CUBESET function returns the appropriate set:

```
CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
    "NONEMPTY([CohortGrowth].[MonthNo].CHILDREN,
        ([CohortGrowth].[CohortYear].&[2],
         [CohortGrowth].[Cohort].&[Denver]))")
```

`= {1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}`

#### The CUBEVALUE with a slicer filter returns the appropriate value:

```
CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
    "[Measures].[Sum of NewGDC]",
    "[CohortGrowth].[CohortYear].&[1]",
    "[CohortGrowth].[Cohort].&[Denver]",
    Slicer_Month_Denver)
```

`= $118,470`

*Slicer_Month_Denver has selected {1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}*

#### But, when replacing the slicer with the CUBESET in the CUBEVALUE formula, the result is *blank* (a zero string result):

```
CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
    "[Measures].[Sum of NewGDC]",
    "[CohortGrowth].[CohortYear].&[1]",
    "[CohortGrowth].[Cohort].&[Denver]",
    CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
        "NONEMPTY([CohortGrowth].[MonthNo].CHILDREN,
            ([CohortGrowth].[CohortYear].&[2],
             [CohortGrowth].[Cohort].&[Denver]))"))
```

`= [blank]`

I also tried putting the CUBESET into a separate cell and referencing the cell but it's the same result.

There are examples of embedding CUBESET into a CUBEVALUE [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080246/excel-cubevalue-cubeset-count-records-greater-than-a-number) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603580/excel-cubevalue-memberexpression/34803837#34803837).

### Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you see what your CUBESET is returning?

Comment: I use CUBESETCOUNT to find out how many values are in the set and then I use CUBERANKEDMEMBER to see what each value is